# UIWebView "Unable to read document" error

Tags: iphone, ipad

I am trying to open Word and Excel 2003 docs using loadRequest and I am getting this error
(in simulator).
Unable to Read Document.
An error occurred while reading the document.

According to this link, 
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#qa/qa2008/qa1630.html

UIWebView should display doc and xls types.

Any ideas? 
Are there any other recommended xls, doc viewers out there?

Thanks.

Comment: Do the same docs open in the Safari app on the device?

Comment: No. I get the same message in Safari. I am able to open pdf files, but not word or excel.

Comment: Check the url and that the docs are not corrupt or encrypted.

Comment: Here is a [possible duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4271379/detect-and-customize-uiwebviews-unable-to-read-document-error).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason i found int these case was due to `password` `protected` or `encrypted` file,or any file format which `webview` can `load`.

UIWebView has these `EXCEPTION SFUZipEndOfCentralDirectoryError: Could not find the end of central directory record` when it encounter with above reason.

You can load document like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17167845/1106035)

Comment: how to show .xls url string in webview in swift @Paresh

Comment: @DilipTiwari https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uidocumentinteractioncontroller

Comment: how can i show .xls file after saving path to webview