# NSRangeException while opening local .doc files on webview

Tags: ios, exception, unicode, uiwebview, uiwebviewdelegate

I am trying to open a downloaded .doc file in UIWebview on iPad.
Basically .doc file have unicode character in both file name & file content which i am trying to open .

I got following error logs in console

```
WebKit discarded an uncaught exception in the webView:decidePolicyForNavigationAction:request:frame:decisionListener: delegate: <NSRangeException> *** -[NSArray objectAtIndex:]: index 0 beyond bounds for empty array
```

But neither webview's  **didFailLoadWithError** or **webViewDidFinishLoad** delegate is called so how can i trap the error .What could be reason for it?

Answer (score 0):

I've seen a few questions like this here before.

Such as:

[Displaying ppt, doc, and xls in UIWebView doesn't work but pdf does](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2520137/displaying-ppt-doc-and-xls-in-uiwebview-doesnt-work-but-pdf-does)

and

[UIWebView does not open ms word (doc) and ms excel (xls) files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5941562/uiwebview-does-not-open-ms-word-doc-and-ms-excel-xls-files)

You might find some helpful hints in those questions.

Does the file open correctly when you download it on a Macintosh?

Is the mime type set correctly?

What else have you implemented in your UIWebViewDelegate?