# Change text colour in UIWebView

Tags: objective-c, uiwebview

I am loading a Word document in a `UIWebView`. Can I make the text color of the document white with a black background?

I use this code to add a black background, but the text color is grey (not white):

```
[self.view setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
[self.webView setOpaque:NO];
[self.webView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
```

Comment: How do you display the word document in the UIWebView? Can you post your code?

Comment: set your document text color white and load in webview

Answer (score 2):

You can change text color and backgorund color in `UIWebView` using this code.

```
- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)_webView{

    [self.webView setOpaque:NO];
    NSString *setJavaScript = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].style.webkitTextFillColor= 'white';document.getElementsByTagName('div')[0].style.backgroundColor='black'; DOMReady();"];
    [self.webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:setJavaScript];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Hex color's

```
[self.itemSummary loadHTMLString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"<html><body bgcolor=\"#000000\" text=\"#FFFFFF\" face=\"Bookman Old Style, Book Antiqua, Garamond\" size=\"5\">%@</body></html>", [item objectForKey:@"description"]] baseURL: nil];
```

http://www.color-hex.com/

Comment: I open MS Word document in UIWEBView, not HTML.

Answer (score 0):

A UIWebView display method is the same as displaying a web page. So to adjust the display, you can use CSS.

For example, you can use CSS to display all text in white color:

```
body { color: #FFFFFF;}
```

So just add those CSS rules wrapped in style tag:

```
NSString *stringWithWhiteFont = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"<style>body { color: #FFFFFF;}</style>%@", css, htmlStringToBeDisplayed];
[webView stringWithWhiteFont baseURL:nil];
```

And I am not sure how you display the word document in a UIWebView. It seems you need to use UIDocumentController to open word document.

[UIWebView does not open ms word (doc) and ms excel (xls) files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5941562/uiwebview-does-not-open-ms-word-doc-and-ms-excel-xls-files)

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIDocumentInteractionController_class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009304